# Secondary router only gets half speed

Tags: internet-speed, netgear-router

I have a Netgear R6400v2 as my main primary router connected to a fiber connection. To that router I have another Netgear R6400 connected with cat 4 or 5 lan cable as a secondary router set as an access point (I didn’t install it and it is in the wall but from its age I am guessing cat 4 but more likely 5).

My computer is connected to the secondary router with a cat 6 cable and I seem to have some speed issues.

I have a Nighthawk app for Netgear and when I speed test the primary router, the test results are always around 100 mbps while speed test on the secondary results always around 50 mbps.

Where should I be looking for issues?

Comment: If you are really using CAT 4 cable, that is slow cable and the likely source of your issue. CAT 5e  supports fast speeds and even it has been out for a while.

Comment: It's definitely not CAT4 because the max speed is 16 Mbps.

Comment: Ok so it is definitely not a cat 4 cable. Now I know not to worry about that, but any ideas what is it that I should check?